# Picking a suitable GUI framework for project

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I have a project where I have to show some sort of changing bar graph with results from a function. This bar graph should be in colour and 3d. I want it to look good since it's an open source educational program where it teaches the user about different voting systems and how they effect the outcome of an election. I would like to use python but I have no idea about using GUI frameworks since all my work in python has been command line based. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at matplotlib, which is probably the most widely used library for doing graphs, including 3-D.

Comment: Seconded, matplotlib's a great choice - works well with all the major UI toolkits as a widget, works with [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to make a stand-alone app, etc.  Have a look at the [gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html), in particular there's a [3D Histogram](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html) near the end that might be worth a look.

Comment: An educational *website* can have a much wider reach than a program that has to installed.  Check out this html5 backend for matplotlib: http://code.google.com/p/mplh5canvas/

Answer (score 3):

<s>For 3D graphics, you might want to use OpenGL with a game framework, such as [PyGame](http://pygame.org/news.html) or [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/).</s> Use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) as TJD suggested in the other answer.

---

As for GUI frameworks, they generally won't help much with 3D graphics:

[PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) is one choice; I see you already have it in the question tags. [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) is very similar to PyQt, but with a nicer licence.

Then there's [tkinter](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html) (in the standard library), [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/), and [pyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/) – I hear all of them are good, though I don't know them personally.

Pick one and stay with it. It'll take some time to learn if you're not experienced, so don't expect results too soon.